Include non-repo LaTeX Packages in .Rmd in Shiny App
I have an R shiny app that allows for the rendering and download of pdfs using Rmarkdown and tinytex. The .Rmd files use several LaTeX packages, one of which (digsig) is not available in the default tinytex repository. On my personal computer, I manually installed the digsig.sty file into my tinytex library. However, this shinyapp is being uploaded to RConnect via the RStudio publishing tool, and so this is not possible in "deployment".
I believe the simplest solution is to include the digsig.sty file within the directory of my shinyapp (in the folder titled "latex") and reference it directly, somehow. I have library(tinytex) and library(rmarkdown) and the packages load fine. I can see in the logs that pandoc is unable to find the digsig.sty file, but I am unsure how to make it available.
Here is what I have tried so far:
In .Rmd header:
- \usepackage{digsig}
- \usepackage{latex/digsig/}
- \usepackage{latex/disgig}
- \graphicspath{latex/}
- \usepackage{latex/digsig/digsig}

I've also tried tinytex::tlmgr('install --file "latex/digsig/digsig.sty" digsig') within the app.R file to attempt to install the local package manually with tlmgr directly.
None of these options worked, and I am stumped! Am I misunderstanding how file paths work in rmarkdown or latex? Again,\usepackage{digsig} works fine on my machine, just not when deployed to RConnect.

You could try copying both the digsig.sty file and the .tex file that you are processing to the same temporary directory, and do the processing there.  Or put the file in an R package and use system.file() to find it.

@user2554330 Is this feasible in a R shiny app deployment? I don't know enough about the tmlgr / tinytex / rmarkdown environment to manipulate system files from within a shiny app. Do you mean like send out bash commands to the server from within the app?

I don't know much about Shiny, so I'm assuming it acts like any R script.  You don't need bash commands, you just use base R functions like file.copy() to copy the file.  The system.file() function doesn't work with "system files", it's just a way to find where a particular file from a package was installed.

@user2554330 The issue isn't really finding the file, it's telling tinytex / pandoc / rmarkdown where to find it in order to use it. Just to be clear, this is a LaTeX package, not an R package.

Yes, I understood that.  What you want is to put the .sty file in the same place as the .tex file, then LaTeX will just use it.  I was assuming that was the place where the .Rmd file was found, but maybe it's somewhere else.
